# How update passwords of user's already existing in ldap?

Tags: linux, ldap, unix, openldap

I want to update passwords [user's already existing in ldap] of the user by importing data from `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`.

How to achieve this?

I will give the overview of my setup.

1. Nodes user id & password managed by management node [xcat], ldap not used for this purpose.
2. We have imported the user's from management node to ldap server by following the below given steps:-

a. I copied `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group` & `/etc/shadow` from the management node.

b. I ran the following:

```
getent passwd > /tmp/passwd.out
getent shadow > /tmp/shadow.out
cd /usr/share/migrationtools/
./migrate_passwd.pl /tmp/passwd.out > /tmp/passwd.ldif
ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=aadityaldap,dc=com" -f /tmp/passwd.ldif
```

Now we want to update the passwords frequently and keep the ldap server sync with out management node. please give me idea how to achive this.

I tried the same way i imported users into ldap but it gives me an error.

```
[root@iitmserver2 migrationtools]# ldapmodify -x -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=aadityaldap,dc=com" -f /tmp/passwd.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
ldapmodify: modify operation type is missing at line 2, entry "uid=pharthiphan,ou=People,dc=aadityaldap,dc=com"
[root@iitmserver2 migrationtools]#
```

Comment: The error message `ldapmodify: modify operation type is missing at line 2` is a pretty big hint that the LDIF file is not valid/suitable for what you're trying to do. - Additionally normally once your users are in an LDAP directory you configure your servers to authenticate against that directory and move away from the passwd and shadow files., which makes your whole keeping in sync issue a non-issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your .ldif file is formatted incorrectly. After you have gotten the password you need to put it in a correctly formatted .ldif:

`dn: <DN TO EDIT>
changetype: modify
userPassword: <NEW PASSWORD>`

If you have the file like this then look for whitespace, LDAP really doesn't like it. If not then, edit the script you have put above to include the correctly formatted .ldif and call it in a cron job to run at given times/intervals:

http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml